# Time.zone.at different from Time.zone in Ruby On Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9.2

Here is what I am doing in console:

```
1.9.2p290 :018 > Time.zone = 'Brasilia'
 => "Brasilia" 

1.9.2p290 :020 >  Time.zone.now
 => Fri, 17 Aug 2012 13:08:06 BRT -03:00 

1.9.2p290 :021 > Event.last.start_time
 => 2000-01-01 03:45:00 UTC 

1.9.2p290 :022 > Time.zone.at(event.start_time)
 => Sat, 01 Jan 2000 01:45:00 BRST -02:00
```

Why is the last sentence returning a different timezone?

Comment: DST, wikipedia to rescue http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Brazil#Bras.C3.ADlia_official_time_-_BRT_.28UTC-03.29

Comment: I see, but the timezone that it is set is -03:00, not -02:00

Comment: The timezone is BRT, not BRST, I don't understand why Time.zone.at changes it

Comment: I am not sure about BRST, but as clearly mentioned on wiki article Brazil's time advances in October and is rolled back in February

Comment: Yeah, we are not in that period. The current timezone in Brazil is -03:00 , why Time.zone.at is returning another timezone?

Comment: I made the same mistake, I was comparing a date of january with a date of february and the difference of days was wrong by one our because of this damn daylight saving hour.